# Php recursive function got error exception

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, exception, request

I want to make a recursive function, which function call itself,
I have `public function test(Request $request){}` where inside that function I called itself

```
public function test(Request $request){
  //data
  $data // this variable is have the same format as $request, but with fewer data
  if (count($data>0){
    test($data);
  }
}
```

but it returns

```
Argument 1 passed to App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\Controller::test() must be an instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, array given, called in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\FIX\\test\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\Controller.php on line 891",
```

Comment: test($request, $data)

Comment: Can you add what you have at $data = ?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge new data with the old request and pass the request again to the function recursively.

```
public function test(Request $request){

  if (count($data>0){
    $request->merge($data);
    test($request);
  }
}
```

By doing this, your new data will be passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest this way

```php
public function test(Request $request, array $data = []){
  if (!empty($data) {
    $this->test($request, $data);
  }
}
```